# How to access other partitions/disks?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, mount

There was an icon called "My Computer" to Ubuntu 11.04 that allowed access to all available disks and partitions.

However, I could not find anything similar in Ubuntu 11.10.

Anyone know if this feature was removed?

Comment: Do you mean the 'computer:///' location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'computer:///' location still works in 11.10, but apparently, the button has been removed. Hit ctrl+l to show the location bar in Nautilus, type in 'computer:///' and bookmark it.

All available partitions should also show in the left side panel.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Is there another (obvious) way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can check all partitions by running

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null

cd /media
sudo mkdir drive1
```

Now you can mount

```
sudo mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/drive1
```